# vmware cli command resxtop not found on 64 bit ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, esxi

I installed `VMware-vSphere-CLI-4.1.0-254719.x86_64` on 64-bit Ubuntu 10.10 and I'm having an issue.

When I try to run resxtop it says:

> exec: 527: /usr/lib/vmware-vcli/bin/resxtop: not found

What should I do? The file is clearly both in that location and in `/usr/bin/resxtop`

Answer (score 1):

According to the [VMWare Forums,](http://community.zenoss.org/docs/DOC-9384) the correct way to fix this is to install:

`sudo apt-get install libssl-dev perl-doc liburi-perl libxml-libxml-perl libcrypt-ssleay-perl ia32-libs`

(Note, this is a big job, it downloads ~80Mb of stuff, and takes ~260Mb of disk space)